# upload multiple files with multer?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, multer

I just can't figured whats wrong why my codes below. I try to upload multiple files.
The problem is that i had an "UNEXPECTED FIELD"
I can make it to upload single file just fine, but I can't make it upload multiple files. So what's wrong here?

html

```
<input id="file" type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Imagen" name="image" multiple>
```

component.js

```
var payload = new FormData();
var files =  $('#file')[0].files

        for (key in $scope.producto) {
            payload.append(key, $scope.producto[key])
            console.log($scope.producto[key])
        }


     if (files.length > 0) {

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var file = files[i];
                    console.log(file)
                    console.log(files.length)
                    payload.append('image', file);
                }
            }
       $http.post('http://localhost:5001/api/v1/articles', payload, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { "Content-Type": undefined },
        }).then(function (response) {
            $location.path("/")
        })
```

Here's the server part:

```
const multer = require('multer')
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : function(req, file, cb){
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
filename : function(req, file, cb){
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname)
}

})

const upload = multer({storage : storage, limits: {
    fileSize : 1024 * 1024 * 5 
}})


.post('/api/v1/articles/', upload.array('image', 2 ), controllerArticle.postArticles)
```

controllerArticle.js

```
function postArticles(req, res) {
    // console.log(req.file)
if (req.file) {

const nvo = new articulos({
    name: req.body.name,
    price: req.body.price,
    condition: req.body.condition,
    brand: req.body.brand,
    productImage: req.file.path
})
nvo.save((err, productStored) => {
    if (err) res.status(500)

    res.status(200).send({ nvo: productStored })
})
}
}
```

I have tried so far:

Change upload.array() to upload.any(),and doesn't work..
any help? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Already solved... The problem was in the controller. 
Is req.files not req.file (singular).
if I just need to upload one file it's req.file and to multiple files is req.files.

Comment: Wow... Had the exact same problem